# Redirection of kernel messages to another device than /dev/tty01

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have a BeagleBone-like device and have enabled CDC ACM so I can login using USB. That part works just fine, but I can't figure out how to redirect the kernel messages, so I can see the messages during the login. Normally I have the kernel output at `/dev/tty01` and logging in using this serial port works fine, also with kernel output. The CDC ACM device is called `/dev/ttyGS0`.

It would be fine just to be able to redirect kernel messages after login.

I have tried stuff like:

```
dmesg | tail -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another `console=ttyGS0,<mode>` to your kernel command line to log to the serial port.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work because the device ttyGS0 is ready to late. I found out that it takes a patch and a delay in init/main (as fare as I remember). I think I have to live with a solution lige the dmesg | tail -f and so fare I do. I appreciate you answer, so thank you!